# How do I escape bash keywords that match up with python keywords?

Tags: python, bash, command-line, escaping, keyword

Example - any bash keyword (e.g. `else` or `in`) will also cause this:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;for p in sys.path:print p'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys;for p in sys.path:print p
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Double quotes doesn't fix it.

Comment: Causes what? What's the error?

Comment: I believe you have a syntax error; you've omitted the rest of the error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Correct, I've added it back in.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - it causes the invalid syntax. If I use other commands that don't include bash keywords - e.g. `$ python -c 'import sys;print "/home" in sys.path'`, everything is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that `for` is a Bash keyword; it's simply that

```
import sys;for p in sys.path:print p
```

is not valid Python syntax. You'd get the same error if you ran `python` with no arguments and then typed that in at the prompt.

You can fix it by adding a newline:

```
import sys
for p in sys.path:print p
```

which you can do in your Bash command by writing either this:

```
python -c ' import sys
            for p in sys.path:print p
          '
```

or this:

```
python -c $'import sys\nfor p in sys.path:print p'
```

(where `$'...'` is a Bash syntax that allows C-like escape sequences in strings, such as `\n` for newline).

Comment: Are you sure? For loops work fine (`$ python -c 'for i in range(5):print i'`), and semicolon concatenation works fine after import (`$ python -c 'import sys;print "/home" in sys.path'`)... What is it about my syntax that's incorrect?

Comment: Python appears to not like any compound statement (`for`, `while`, `def`, etc) after a semicolon.  For example, `x = 1; while False: pass` results in a syntax error.

Comment: See the [grammar](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html).  If I'm reading correctly, you can only join `small_stmt`s with semicolons, and those include `(expr_stmt | print_stmt  | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt | import_stmt | global_stmt | exec_stmt | assert_stmt)` but do not include `compound_stmt`s (`if_stmt | while_stmt | for_stmt | try_stmt | with_stmt | funcdef | classdef | decorated`).  It looks like `something; something else: a third something` is ruled out because `something else` isn't simple.

Comment: @GaryFixler: The semicolon-instead-of-newline notation has its limits; in particular, compound statements cannot be delimited by semicolons. (I think it's obvious why they can't be terminated by a semicolon: otherwise, `for a in (1,2,3): print a; print "\n"` would be ambiguous. As for why they can't be preceded by a semicolon, I think it's just a matter of symmetry, clarity, and consistency.)

Comment: My [incorrect] presumption was that with semicolon, you get one statement after the block statement, and my [also incorrect] guess was that to squeeze in more, one would group statements with parentheses. I.e. `for a in (1,2,3): (print "next value:"; print "a"); print "done"` vs. `for a in (1,2,3): print a; print "done"`. That's not inline with Python style, but it made sense as I was thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
python -c "exec(\"import sys;\\nfor p in sys.path:print p\")"
```

Comment: The exec statement supports dynamic execution of Python code. The first parameter, if a string, is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs).

Comment: That does work. Do I really need to do all of this? I was hoping to be able to throw a few query loops at things, but this syntax would be pretty rough to deal with all the time.

Comment: That probably works because of the `\n` after the first statement; see @ruakh's answer.

Comment: I agree. Newline is important.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more approach....Bit more direct

```
python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"
```

Comment: join returns a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable (sys.path in this case). The separator between elements is the string providing this method which in this case is the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

It works if the semicolon and the `compound_stmt` keyword aren't adjacent:

```
# instead of '; for'
python -c 'import sys; print [p for p in sys.path]'
```

or

```
# instead of '; if'
python -c "x=1; print x if x>0 else ''"
```